# report builder 3.0 connection to Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, oracle10g, reporting

this is the first time i work with report builder 3.0 and oracle database.
I want to create a report using Report builder 3.0 to an oracle database "TEST"
i created the datasource using connection type "Oracle" and "OLE DB", the Connection Test succeeded.
[image]

however if i create a dataset using any of the above datasources, i cannot find list of database tables and views in query designer.
also if i try to write manually a query "select * from GCL_CLAIM_TRANSACTIONS", i receive an error "table does not exist ORA-00903: Invalid Table Name", knowing that if i run the same query from "Benthic Software: Golden", it works properly .
[image]
[image]

Appreciate your assistance,
thanks

Comment: Note that you must be sure that this table exists on the default schema of the currently logged in user, otherwise, you need to specify which schema this table belongs to.

Comment: how to do that???
also shouldn't i get a visual interface for tables and views once connected in the dataset (same as sqp server database)???

Comment: indeed when i entered the username igeneral instead of system it worked. i thought that system username can access all modules.
Thanks
i still have one more question, is there a way to see the list of table and views in the dataset once connected, instead of only writing sql query (this feature do exist if connecting to sql database)

Comment: System can indeed access everything, but the default schema for igeneral and system users are not the same, by default the schema of a user its the user name so, if logged in as system, you need to do a select from the igeneral.GCL_CLAIM_TRANSACTIONS table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing connection type "**Oracle"**, after giving user name and password, just **check** the **“Save my password”**. You should be good now after that.

Comment: Just looked into your screen shot “Benthic Software:Golden”. Seems like you have logged in there using igeneral@test with some password.
Can you give same details in SSRS datasource?
Server Name: test
User Name: igeneral
Password : <used for igeneral>

Comment: indeed when i entered the username igeneral instead of system it worked. i thought that system username can access all modules.
Thanks
i still have one more question, is there a way to see the list of table and views in the dataset once connected, instead of only writing sql query

Comment: Yes.
Open your dataset - > click on query designer -> right click on top white area -> you will see Add table option there

Comment: i did right click on the top white area, but add table didnt show, i only got: Undo, cut, copy , paste delete, select all, right to left reading order, show unicode control caracters, insert unicode control caracter, open IME, reconversion @Aftab